# Ошибка отправки AJAX запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь отправить AJAX запрос, но что-то идёт не так. При нажатий запрос возвращает undefined. В чём проблема?

```
//HTML
<div id="start"></div>

//JQUERY
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "work.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.text)
            }
        });
    });
});

//work.php
<?php echo "Hello World!";
```

Comment: `alert(data)` *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо за отклик. ".text" тут однозначно лишнее.